# How to extract rows and save as a text file in linux

Tags: linux

I have a dataset of one column and 500 rows, for which I would like to extract each line and save it as an individual file, so I end up with 500 files.
The data looks like this:

```
100002
100003
100004
100005
100006
100007
...
```

and I want each of these numbers in their own file.
For my level of coding I can understand maybe doing some like;

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 {print $0}'  wholefile.txt> individual1.txt
```

might work with manually changing the numbers, but how do I set this up to iterate through each line and also change the file being created so they are uniquely named such as individual1, individual2, etc.

For example opening individual1.txt would show me 100001, but the file name would not be individual10001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
count = 0
for i in `cat wholefile.txt`
do
# or let count=count+1
count=$((count+1))
echo $i >> individual$count.txt
done
```

Comment: This will overwrite a file if there are two identical lines.

Comment: Thank you for your post and comments, luckily for me each line is unique so this works. However for the names of the files they are the individual numbers instead of 'individual1' 'individual2' etc. Is there a way for me in this code to stipulate the file to be called individual{number}? If that makes sense

Comment: @DN1 just updated the code for the same, please consider up voting and accepting the answer if it solves your issues so that its clear for others that issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you for this. An issue for me is that I don't want the $i number to be the number that is in the row in the original dataset, I just want it to go 1,2,3,4,5 and so on (even though the number in the file would be like 123439 or something), is this possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible if your file contains 1000 lines, then do you want the file names to be like `individual998` etc ?

Comment: Yes like that although I have only 502 lines in my file

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this gave me files such as: individual+1+1+1+1 and so on

Comment: Updated the answer. Also as mentioned previously please accept the answer if your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the trailing `.txt` in the file names you could use the `split` command

```
split -l 1 -d -a 3 wholefile.txt individual
```

This will create files with sequentially numbered suffix `individual000`, `individual001` etc. up to the number of lines in `wholefile.txt`. The numbers don't depend on the contents of `wholefile.txt` .

See `man split`

> ```
> -d     use numeric suffixes starting at 0, not alphabetic
>
> -a, --suffix-length=N
>           generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
>
> --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]
>           same as -d, but allow setting the start value
>
> -l, --lines=NUMBER
>           put NUMBER lines/records per output file
> ```

The option argument `-a 3` creates numbers of 3 digits. You might have to change this depending on the number of lines in `wholefile.txt`. The leading zeros make sure the files can be sorted in lexicographical order.

If you want to start the numbers with 1 instead of 0, replace `-d` with `--numeric-suffixes=1`.

---

If you want to remove the leading zeros you can use a script to rename the files after splitting. You can also append `.txt` if necessary.

```
for file in individual*
do
    newname="$(echo $file|sed 's/\([^0]*\)\(0*\)\([0-9]\)/\1\3/').txt"
    mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```

The `sed` command searches for three groups

- `[^0]*` 0 or more characters that are not `0`
- `0*` 0 or more `0` characters
- `[0-9]` a digit from `0` to `9`

and replaces this pattern by the 1st and 3rd group omitting the 2nd group.
This works here because the prefix `individual` doesn't contain numbers. Otherwise the `sed` command would have to be extended.

Comment: Thank you for this and including the explanations. Would there be a way to designate the individual{number} file name being in ascending numbers (1,2,3,4 etc.) but not being the number that is actually in the line of the original dataset?

Comment: @DN1 The files will be created with ascending numbers but with 0-padding. I changed the suffix from 6 digits to 3 digits to show that it doesn't correspond to the numbers in the file.

Comment: cleanest answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop over the line numbers together with a `sed` command that prints the line. The output is written to the individual files as intended.

```
for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -l wholefile.txt | grep -o '^ *[0-9]\+')); do
    sed -n "${i}p" wholefile.txt > invidividual${i}.txt
done
```

Note that for 500 files, the output file names won't be properly formatted. You might want to replace the above file name with `invidividual$(printf "%03d" ${i}).txt`.

Answer (score 0):

A pure bash solution is

```
j=0; while read -r line; do echo "$line" > "individual.$((j++)).txt"; done < file
```

An awk solution would be

```
awk '{f=sprintf("individual.%0.5d.txt",NR); "print > f; close(f) }' file
```

A pure split solution

```
split -l 1 -d -a 5 --additional-suffix ".txt" file individual.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while read -r line;` to read file line by line and write to it with `echo`

```
user@vmdeb ~ % cat nums.txt 
100001
100002
100003
100004
100005
user@vmdeb ~ % while read -r line; do echo "$line" > "$line".txt; done < nums.txt
user@vmdeb ~ % ls
100001.txt  100002.txt  100003.txt  100004.txt  100005.txt nums.txt
user@vmdeb ~ % cat 100001.txt 
100001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

---

```
count = 1

cat wholefile.txt | while read line ;
do
    echo $line >> individualtextfile_$count.txt
    count=$[count+1]
done
```

---

Comment: You don't need `cat`. Simply use `while read line; do ... done < wholefile.txt`. This has the advantage that the loop is not executed in a subshell. Do `echo count $count` after the loop to see the difference.

Comment: Yeah, it is true. Thanks!